# Dynamic navigation entry creation in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

The idea is to create new navigation items according to what push from the server. If user asked new functionality (custom) navigation option should appear on the navigator and that will navigate to a view which have already define in the application. Is there any sample code or library to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is more like a conceptual question, need to know the possibility